# ¿Cómo manejar una excepción dentro de un ciclo while?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones, websocket

Estoy desarrollando un script que me permite obtener cotizaciones de divisas en tiempo real, esto lo hago mediante un API que funciona con websockets, cada cierto tiempo la aplicación se desconecta y me devuelve la siguiente excepción:

```
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 113, in send
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException("socket is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: socket is already closed.
```

Y trato de capturarla con `try-except` dentro de un bucle while (el que se encarga de obtener las cotizaciones), este es mi código:

**EDITADO:** Por alguna razón no puedo eliminar la primera conexión del API y solo usarla en la función `conectar()`, eso es por recomendación de la documentación de la misma.

```
from iqoptionapi.api import IQOptionAPI
from datetime import datetime
import time
from operator import itemgetter

api = IQOptionAPI("iqoption.com", "usuario", "contraseña")
api.connect()

def conectar(id_activo):
    velas = None
    while velas == None:
        print("Intento de conexión...")
        api = IQOptionAPI("iqoption.com", "usuario", "contraseña")
        api.connect()
        api.getcandles(id_activo, 1)
        velas = api.candles.candles_data

def obtener_velas(id_activo):
    try:
        api.getcandles(id_activo, 1) # produce una excepción cuándo el websocket pierde conexión con el servidor
    except:
        print("¡Desconexión!") # intentar reconectar el websocket una sola vez
    time.sleep(1)
    if api.candles.candles_data[-1][2] != 0:
        cierre = api.candles.candles_data[-1][2] / 1000000
    else:
        cierre = api.candles.candles_data[-2][2] / 1000000

    vela =[api.candles.candles_data[1][0],
           api.candles.candles_data[1][1] / 1000000,
           max(api.candles.candles_data, key=itemgetter(2))[3] / 1000000,
           min(api.candles.candles_data, key=itemgetter(2))[4] / 1000000,
           cierre]
    return vela

while True:
    velas = api.candles.candles_data
    if not velas is None:
        while datetime.now().second != 0:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        vela = obtener_velas(1)
        print(vela)
    else:
        conectar(1)
        print("Conexión establecida\n")
```

La salida normal del programa, sin excepciones es esta:

```
Intento de conexión...
Intento de conexión...
Conexión establecida

[1485969661, 1.07509, 1.07519, 1.075105, 1.075105]
[1485969721, 1.075105, 1.075245, 1.075145, 1.075145]
[1485969781, 1.075145, 1.075145, 1.07508, 1.075095]
```

Pero cuándo levanta una excepción me da esto:

```
Intento de conexión...
Intento de conexión...
Conexión establecida

[1485969661, 1.07509, 1.07519, 1.075105, 1.075105]
Intento de conexión...
[1485969721, 1.075105, 1.075245, 1.075145, 1.075145]
Intento de conexión...
[1485969781, 1.075145, 1.075145, 1.07508, 1.075095]
Conexión establecida
```

Sigue ejecutando el bloque de `except` aún cuándo ya recupere la conexión, yo esperaría que solo ejecutara una vez el bloque que soluciona la excepción y siguiera con la ejecución normal del programa, pero no lo hace, y se sigue así, hasta que provoca una nueva excepción pero ahora en `urlib3` por exceso de peticiones. ¿Cómo puedo lograr que se ejecute una sola vez mi bloque de `except` recupere la conexión con el websocket y siga la ejecución del programa?

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema no es con las excepciones, esas están funcionando bien, el problema está en la lógica. Ahí estuve viendo el código y creo que encontré una manera mas legible, simple y rápida de solucionarlo, ya que había mucho código repetido, y se rebuscaba bastante con los ciclos. Acá te dejo el código, no pude testearlo porque no tengo la API incorporada, pero avisame cualquier cosa:

```
from iqoptionapi.api import IQOptionAPI
from datetime import datetime
import time
from operator import itemgetter

api = IQOptionAPI("iqoption.com", "usuario", "contraseña")


def obtener_velas(id_activo):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    velas = None
    while velas == None:
        try:
            print("Intento de conexión...")
            api.connect()
            api.getcandles(id_activo, 1)
            velas = api.candles.candles_data
        except:
            logging.exception('Error al conectarse')
            time.sleep(0.5)

    print("Conexión establecida")
    time.sleep(1)

    if velas[-1][2] != 0:
        cierre = velas[-1][2] / 1000000
    else:
        cierre = velas[-2][2] / 1000000

    vela = [velas[1][0],
               velas[1][1] / 1000000,
               max(velas, key=itemgetter(2))[3] / 1000000,
               min(velas, key=itemgetter(2))[4] / 1000000,
               cierre]
    return vela


while True:
    vela = obtener_velas(1)
    print(vela)
    while datetime.now().second != 0:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

**Update:**

Como bien dijo @FZNB poner un `pass` puede saturar bastante al programa. Ahí agregué un `logging` para poder debuguear en caso de error y un `sleep` para no sobrecargar mucho

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos!

Comment: Esta versión es mucho más legible, pero ese `except: pass` es "diabólico". Mejor, tal y como se indica en [este enalce](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/), añadir un `logging` para documentar y quizás un `sleep` para no saturar la API, ¿no? 
;)

Comment: Gracias por el comentario! No conocía la función `logging`, y es verdad lo del tiempo

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda! pero en realidad, el programa ha dejado de hacer lo que tenia que hacer,  sigue intentando conectarse cada vez que envía una petición de vela y ahora ya no las obtiene cada minuto.

Comment: Arroja algún error o algo por el estilo?

Comment: No, ninguno pero por ejemplo ya no obtiene las cotizaciones minuto a minuto y cada vez que llama a la función obtener_velas() intenta conectarse. A ver lo estoy tratando de hacer más entendible con la excepción y la funcionalidad que quiero, te lo muestro y me puedes ayudar porfavor?

Comment: Por supuesto! Editá la pregunta y avisame!

Comment: Listo, ya lo edite. Espero que el código sea más legible, me cuesta un poco de trabajo la lógica aún. ¿Si se entiende?

Comment: Buenisimo! Si llego a sacar algo te aviso!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52904/discussion-between-genarito-and-samael-olascoaga).